# Radio button working in Firefox but not clickable in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, radio-button

I have created these radio buttons.

They work perfectly in Firefox, but they're not clickable in Chrome.

Here's the code:

```
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" id="radio_btn">1</input>
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" id="radio_btn">2</input>
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" id="radio_btn">3</input>
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" id="radio_btn">4</input>
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" id="radio_btn">5</input>
<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="1" /><br/>
<input style = "margin-left:88px;margin-top:10px;" type="submit" id="sub_rating" value="Vote" />
```

This is the CSS:

```
#radio_btn {
  margin-left : 3%;
  margin-right : 3%;
}
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Use classes here instead.

Comment: [Works perfectly](http://jsfiddle.net/yanFV/) in chrome too!

Comment: input tag does not have closing tag i.e </input>. standard to write a input tag like this <input type="text" name="name" /> not closing it with a </input>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must for first delete `</input>` then change id they must not be the same and you delete the style of the submit button.
for the css you write the css code using your `<form>` id like this

```
<form id="youID">
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" id="radio_btn_1">1
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" id="radio_btn_2">2
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" id="radio_btn_3">3
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" id="radio_btn_4">4
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" id="radio_btn_5">5
<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="1" /><br/>
<input type="submit" id="sub_rating" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

CSS

```
#youID input[type="radio"] {
margin-left : 3%;
margin-right : 3%;
}
#youID input[type="submit"] {
    margin-left:88px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: This isn't valid HTML, you need to close those `<input>` tags, either with `<input... />` or `<input...>...</input>`.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above, all IDs on a page must be unique.
It is better to use a class for applying styles too.
You should do something like this :

```
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" id="radio_btn1" class="radio_btn">1</input>
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" id="radio_btn2" class="radio_btn">2</input>
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" id="radio_btn3" class="radio_btn">3</input>
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" id="radio_btn4" class="radio_btn">4</input>
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" id="radio_btn5" class="radio_btn">5</input>
```

You'll also need to change your CSS rule to this:

```
.radio_btn {
    margin-left : 3%;
    margin-right : 3%;
}
```